# How to upload the files from the master repo to the fileshare with a ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a template that creates a storage account and a fileshare. Like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "metadata": {
    "_generator": {
      "name": "bicep",
      "version": "0.5.6.12127",
      "templateHash": "3186185032530874094"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "storageAccountName": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[format('storage{0}', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the name of the Azure Storage account."
      }
    },
    "fileShareName": {
      "type": "string",
      "maxLength": 63,
      "minLength": 3,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the name of the File Share. File share names must be between 3 and 63 characters in length and use numbers, lower-case letters and dash (-) only."
      }
    },
    "location": {
      "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "metadata": {
        "description": "Specifies the location in which the Azure Storage resources should be deployed."
      }
    }
  },
  "resources": [
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "sku": {
        "name": "Standard_LRS"
      },
      "properties": {
        "accessTier": "Hot",
        "minimumTlsVersion"  : "TLS1_2",
        "supportsHttpsTrafficOnly": "true"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/fileServices/shares",
      "apiVersion": "2021-04-01",
      "name": "[format('{0}/default/{1}', parameters('storageAccountName'), parameters('fileShareName'))]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageAccountName'))]"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the YAML pipeline, you are using `AzureFileCopy@4` task.

> #[error]Upload to container: 'fsndevinternetsuite' in storage account: 'strdevinternetsuite' with blob prefix: '' failed with error: 'AzCopy.exe exited with non-zero exit code while uploading files to blob storage.'

From the error message, the cause of this issue could be that the Service Principal created by the Service connection does not have sufficient permissions to copy files to the Azure Storage account.

Refer to the following steps to find the service principal and add the **Storage Blob Data Owner & Storage Blob Data Contributor** to the service principal.

Step1: Navigate to **Azure Portal -> AAD -> App registrations** to find the related Service Principal.

Step2: Navigate to Storage account and grant the **Storage Blob Data Owner & Storage Blob Data Contributor** to the service principal.

For more detailed steps, you can refer to this doc: [Assign an Azure role for access to blob data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/assign-azure-role-data-access?tabs=portal)

Or you can change to use the `AzureFileCopy@3` to replace the `AzureFileCopy@4`. You can check if it can work.

Comment: The source Path can be a folder path or file path.  If you are using the files in the repo, you can define the path `$(build.sourcesdirectory)/folder name or file name`

Comment: You can check if the path above can meet your requirement.

Comment: Will the path:`'$(build.sourcesdirectory)/sourcecode'` work or not? If you get any error message, you can share with me.